# what is the difference between `from tensorflow.keras.metrics import binary_accuracy` vs `from tensorflow.metrics import binary_accuracy`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this code that works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import binary_accuracy

# Compile the model
model_4.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=BinaryCrossentropy(),
                metrics=[binary_accuracy])
```

and this one that works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Compile the model
model_4.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=BinaryCrossentropy(),
                metrics=[tf.metrics.binary_accuracy])
```

but this one does not work and I do not understand why:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.metrics import binary_accuracy


# Compile the model
model_4.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=BinaryCrossentropy(),
                metrics=[binary_accuracy])
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.metrics'
```

This should be something simple but I do not understand why I have this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `print(tf.__file__)` then you see the full path to code - on my Linux Mint it is

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow
```

and when you open this folder then you see there is no subfolder `metrics`.

And this is why doesn't work `from tensorflow.metrics import binary_accuracy` which looks for the real subfolder.

But there is a real subfolder `keras.metrics` and works other imports.

---

If you open `__init__.py` in this folder and use the search function in your editor to find `metrics` then you should see

```
if hasattr(_current_module, 'keras'):

   metrics = keras.metrics

   setattr(_current_module, "metrics", metrics)
```

which creates alias `metrics = keras.metrics` and this is why works `tf.metrics.binary_accuracy`